# Magento 2 : Error 'The Option Type to Get Group Instance is Incorrect'

Tags: product, magento-2.1, custom-options, addtocart, input

I have created a custom input type for customizable options. Despite it rendering a fairly complex UI element for the user to interact with, all it actually submits when you click "add to cart" is a hidden text field that it populates via JS.

It appears in the "add to cart" form as expected, but when I try to add the product to the cart I receive following error:

*"The option type to get group instance is incorrect"*

I've searched Google and the only references to this error I can find are in the Magento 2 source code.

I believe it's something to do with Option.php or Options.php, but can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Just out of interest, why was my question edited to completely ruin the grammar?

Comment: it might be a bit late, but did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @jrswgtr In the end I created a custom controller, post the form data to that, and then add the product to the cart programmatically from there.

Answer (score 1):

Please open the product(in which you are facing an issue) at the backend and check customizable options.
In customizable options, option type might be wrongly assigned.
For example,

[image: error in my csase]